# Two server failover using nomad

Tags: docker-compose, orchestration, nomad

I am just learning about orchestrators and it's my first time using any orchestrator (`Nomad` in this case).

Our software (video stream processing related) is installed on user premises, currently we have been using `docker compose` to deploy our software (bunch of services as docker container).

Now we have a client who needs failover and has provided us two physical server, one is to be used as a main server and other as failover. What we'd like to do is have our services installed on both the servers but only run these services on failover when the main server goes down.

We won't like to make any changes to our code. we have one services which process the video streams and raise events (`VA service`) and another service which handles database, users, events etc. (`Client Service`). The `client service` knows about this `VA service` and it assigns work to it. *We don't want these services to be running on failover server when the main server is up since it will cause streams to be processed twice i.e produce duplicate events.*

We are configuring our database in master-master mode so that data is available on failover when main fails ( trying it on postgres (current database), had previously done it on Mysql ).

I have set up nomad on both machines with nomad server and client both on each machine and tried configuring them such that if the machine with nomad leader server and its client shuts down, nomad server on failover should take charge and run tasks on its client, but i am unable to achieve this. If i shutdown the main server nothing happens on failover machine.

```
# Leader config file
datacenter = "dc1"
data_dir   = "/opt/nomad/data"
bind_addr  = "192.168.1.38"
name = "server1"

server {
  enabled          = true
  bootstrap_expect = 2
  server_join {
    retry_join = [
      "192.168.1.38",
      "192.168.1.20",
    ]
    retry_max      = 0
    retry_interval = "15s"
  }
}

client {
  enabled = true
  servers = [
    "192.168.1.38",
    "192.168.1.20",
  ]
}


# Follower config file
datacenter = "dc1"
data_dir   = "/opt/nomad/data"
bind_addr  = "192.168.1.20"
name = "server2"

server {
  enabled          = true
  bootstrap_expect = 2
  server_join {
    retry_join = [
      "192.168.1.38",
      "192.168.1.20",
    ]
    retry_max      = 0
    retry_interval = "15s"
  }
}

client {
  enabled = true
  servers = [
    "192.168.1.38",
    "192.168.1.20",
  ]
}
```

1. Is nomad even the right tool for this situation ?
2. How can i achieve what i am trying using nomad ?

Comment: Why not process on _any_ of the servers? Why not split the load between the servers if both are running? Why one is "main" and the other is "failover"? How do you switch between servers? Typically, you have a proxy and the proxy chooses running healthy instance of the service to service the request. What protocol is used to send the data? https://developer.hashicorp.com/nomad/tutorials/load-balancing/load-balancing

Comment: `We don't want these services to be running on failover server when the main server is up since it will cause streams` I do not follow that part. Consider implementing synchronization between multiple concurrent instances of your service, instead of restricting the service to a singleton. When you run multiple nginx instances, you can connect to _any_ of them. Just don't send data to one of your services. Please describe how the services get the data.

Comment: @KamilCuk currently the design of our application does not implement `synchronization between multiple concurrent instances`  its a legacy application and we are hesitant to change it, and thus this question.

Comment: I gotten clarification on nomad github issues.

`one server agent failing will result in the cluster losing quorum and not being able to elect a leader. Without a leader, the cluster cannot make state writes or make any changes to the cluster state, which includes rescheduling workload.`

Comment: `on nomad github issues` This is about the workings of nomad service, not _your_ service. Why do you care? Nomad will take care of itself. You care about your service. Questions: Why not process on any of the servers? Why not split the load between the servers if both are running? Why one is "main" and the other is "failover"? How do you switch between servers?  What protocol is used to send the data to the service? `the design of our application does not implement` How do you _want_ to implement failover? You want to monitor if "main" is up, if it's not, start failover? What algorithm?

Comment: `not being able to elect a leader` Yes, that happened to me, at best is to have at least 3. But I think with bootstrap_expect=1 you can start Nomad server with single instance, but I am not sure. Overall, Nomad is just a runner - specify a command to run and run it. It's up to you how you want to use it. So how do you _want_ to implement failover in your service?